# How to filter hours in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

If I've a pandas dataframe and I'd like to filter certain hours of every day, for example all data between 10:00 and 16:00

```
                   time      open      high       low     close  tick_volume  spread  real_volume
0   2021-02-23 15:25:00  114990.0  115235.0  114980.0  115185.0        55269       5       235555
1   2021-02-23 15:30:00  115180.0  115215.0  115045.0  115135.0        31642       5       116914
2   2021-02-23 15:35:00  115135.0  115240.0  115055.0  115220.0        29381       5       116516
3   2021-02-23 15:40:00  115220.0  115300.0  115030.0  115060.0        46740       5       184703
4   2021-02-23 15:45:00  115055.0  115075.0  114785.0  114885.0        48185       5       200241
5   2021-03-02 15:40:00  111680.0  111895.0  111580.0  111825.0        38471       5       144735
6   2021-03-02 16:15:00  111820.0  112500.0  111750.0  112270.0        71153       5       278122
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel(path)
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']) #convert column to datetime if not already in that format
df.set_index(['time'], inplace=True) #temporarily put time column into index
df = df.between_time('10:00','16:00') #filter between times
df = df.reset_index() #reset the index to make time a column again
```